# formulating English sentences to logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Consider the following sentences

- "We will play outside tomorrow, **if** there will be no rain"
- "We will play outside tomorrow, **only if** there will be no rain"

Let's denote: $A$ = "play outside tomorrow" and $B$ = "there will be no rain".

Are both of the sentences formulated to $A\implies B$?

Comment: No; "if and only if" is $\Leftrightarrow$; thus, its two "components" cannot both be symbolized as $\Rightarrow$.

Comment: First one: $B \to A$. Second one: $\lnot B \to \lnot A$ or, equivalently, $A \to B$. The natural translation (into propositional logic) of "if $\alpha$, then $\beta$" is $\alpha \to \beta$, and not $\beta \to \alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let A be "it does not rain tomorrow" and B be "we will play outside" (the way you phrased it was backwards from what i think you meant)

then "We will play outside if it does not rain tomorrow" is $A \Rightarrow B$.

and "We will play outside tomorrow, only if it does not rain." is a little trickier, because you said **only if** and not **if and only if**, which is what mauro was referring to ($\iff $). "Only if" here can be thought of as "if you see us playing outside tomorrow, then clearly it did not rain." therefore, $B \Rightarrow A$.

So no, they go in different directions

Answer (score 1):

The first statement, "we will play outside tomorrow, if there will be no rain," is the more normal statement for human beings to make. It says that whether it rains or not is a significant factor in our heroes' decision to play outside tomorrow. Thus, if A is the belief we will play outside tomorrow and B is the belief there will be no rain, then the first statement is the implication B implies A.

The second statement, "we will play outside tomorrow, only if there will be no rain," is a little outlandish. Imagine your friend making this statement and then pulling out a contraption that sucks up all clouds from the sky. For, if the decision is made to actually play outside tomorrow, the weather *will be good*. This is the statement of an implication, namely A implies B using the notation in my first paragraph.